# How to implement client-side filtering for static options loaded from the server?

Tags: javascript, combobox, filtering, webix, suggestbox

I'm trying to set ui.combo's options as a URL:

```
{
  view:"combo",
  options:"https://api.myjson.com/bins/qqf81"
}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/e31c3414

Options are loaded, but AFAICS in such case text typing triggers the server-side filtering, while I need a client-side filter for this control. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Do not know why, but using a suggest url, seems to have the behavior you expect :

```
webix.ui({
  view:"combo",
  suggest: {
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/qqf81" 
  }
});
```

Updated snippet : http://webix.com/snippet/986cb461